# XNA sprite order management during runtime?

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I know that I can change the order drawing sprite (which is in front of the other) by ordering the lines, but how to change that order for example when a button is pressed?

How can I make something like in this game [This is a 2d game which the order of sprites change according to its position](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4YrrXmBWAc)

Comment: You could use `.OrderBy()` on the collection of sprites perhaps.

Comment: I remember something like drawComponent or something like that, I couldnt understand how I can use it to make order change according to position , I would like to know how or if there is another way .

Comment: Frankly, unless you show us where you're having problems in your code, you are unlikely to get an answer, and could get your question closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different `SpriteSortMode` than `Deferred` (the default).  `SpriteSortMode` can be set when you use [a `SpriteBatch.Begin()` with a `SpriteSortMode` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.begin.aspx).

With `Deferred` (the default) the order in which `SpriteBatch.Draw()` is called determines what overlaps what (what you call ordering the lines).  If you use `SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack` or `SpriteSortMode.BackToFront` you can control the order they're drawn by the `layerDepth` parameter of [`SpriteBatch.Draw()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433992.aspx).

So what you'd do is you'd keep track of the value that responds to input and pass it to `SpriteBatch.Draw()`.  For example you have a variable called `float mySpriteZindex` and if a certain button is pressed you increase or decrease `mySpriteZindex`.  Then you can pass that value to `SpriteBatch.Draw()`, and now you have a way to control the order sprites are drawn in by variables.

Comment: so if I set the sprite sort mode to FrontToBack , then the ordering will depend on the float layerDepth parameter of spriteBatch.Draw() ? thanks

Comment: Yes, they get drawn in order of `layerDepth`.  iirc `SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack` goes from 0 to 1, and `.BackToFront` the opposite.